# Timed FadeOut not working

Tags: javascript, html, fadeout

I've been wanting to make an image fadeout after a period of time. I've looked through the same topics found here in Stackoverflow but mine doesn't want to work.

If anyone could take a quick peek at my code I would be very grateful please?

The image I would like to fade is:

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ACC BIC - Business Industry Description</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <!--  Bottom bar navigation -->
        <div class="btn btn-two">
          <span class="btn-two--link"><a href="#.html"></a></span>
          <span class="btn-three--link"><a href="selection-5.html"></a></span>
          <span class="btn-four--link"><a href="index.html"></a></span>
          <img id="myImage" class="email-sent-img" src="images/email-link-sent.png" alt="">
          <script>
          $(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#myImage').fadeOut() }, 5000);
});
          </script>
        </div>
        <!--  Background image -->

        <img class="proto-img" src="images/cards-view-selected.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you given your page a link to the jQuery code. It doesn't look like you have, so the computer can't understand the 
`$(window).load()` event or the `$("#myImage").fadeOut()` method. To fix this just add this line of code into the head section of your page-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

If you would prefer to use a later version of jQuery, you can look on the jQuery website for more information.
If this still doesn't work, try replacing the `$("myImage").fadeOut()` with `$("#myImage").fadeTo("slow",0)`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#image").fadeOut("slow", function () { // Instead of Slow you could add 5000 (5s)
            // fade out complete if you need to run another event
        });
    }, 5000); // fade out starts after 5s
});
```